# How to extend default bean annotated with @ConditionalOnMissingBean?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, autowired, spring-ioc

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50796810/what-does-the-spring-annotation-conditionalonmissingbean-do) to see how "default" beans are implemented in Spring. There is a bean in the parent module of my project that is annotated with `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`. I would like to take this bean and extend it's functionality rather than returning a completely new instance. Example

```
// in parent module

@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
Foo defaultBean() {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.a = 1;
    return foo;
}

// in sub module

@Bean
Foo customBean() {
    Foo foo = /* get reference to defaultBean */;
    foo.a += 1;
    return foo;
}

// In another class

@Autowired
Foo foo;

// foo.a would return 2
```

How would I get a reference to the default bean for purpose of implementing a custom bean?

Answer (score 1):

Before I provide my answer, I want to say that I'm not sure if your approach does what you want. That way you also update the defaultBean properties.

But to your question:
If you have multiple beans from the same type and [can't find out which implementation you want](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/auto-wiring.html), spring takes the one which is later initialized for autowiring. To make sure you can use your default bean in your custom bean, you have to autowire it with the exact name:

```
@Autowired
Foo defaultBean;

@Bean
Foo customBean() {
    Foo foo = this.defaultBean;
    foo.a += 1;
    return foo;
}
```

As you can see, the autowired bean has the exact name which is declared in the @Bean creation. Now everywhere you want to use the customBean you need to use:

```
@Autowired
Foo customBean;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, by default, a Spring Bean is a singleton, the changes you make anywhere on your bean would be visible everywhere.

To keep it where it should be (inside configuration classes) you can autowire the default bean in a configuration class constructor and make the changes you need.

Example:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyBeanConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    public MyBeanConfiguration(MyBean bean) {
        // change bean as you wish
   }
}
```

Comment: That's the thing though, I want the changes to be visible everywhere. `Foo` is used in the parent module as a dependency, I would like to inject my own dependency into the parent module that extends Foo's functionality. How would I go about that?

Comment: All configuration classes (and XML files) are taken into account. It doesn't matter where they are placed (in the parent ou sub module) as long as they are scanned / imported.