# SpringBoot - Register Bean as Rest Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-autoconfiguration

I'm using Spring Boot AutoConfiguration for registering the beans. Need to find a way through which I can register the beans configured via Auto-Configuration as a Rest Controller

`SampleController.java`

```java
public class SampleController
{
    @GetMapping("/sample-path")
    public String sampleMethod()
    {
        return "Sample String";
    }
}
```

`SampleControllerAutoConfiguration.java`

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "some.property", havingValue = "true") // using this property, the parent app may or may not chose to have the Controller Endpoint
public class SampleControllerAutoConfiguration
{
    // Need to register this bean as a controller
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public SampleController sampleController()
    {
        return new SampleController();
    }
}
```

I can't annotate `SampleController` with `@RestController` since it's in the same package as the parent project which imports this and hence get's auto-configured due to Component-Scan

Comment: I did answer but then re-read the question and realised you said you can't do what I was proposing. But then I asked myself why you need to create a TestController at all? Are you attempting to mock the controller for testing purposes?

Comment: @RobEvans Sorry for the confusion. I renamed the Controller. This project is following the 'project', 'project-starter' kind of pattern seen in Spring-Boot projects. In an ideal scenario, this project and the project importing it would be in different packages allowing me to annotate 'SampleController' with 'RestController' and registering it as Bean in the AutoConfiguration would make it usable.  Problem is using this project with a project which has the same package name. Annotating 'SampleController' would automatically register it which is what I want to avoid

Comment: So perhaps this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56903971/7619034

Comment: The problem is, since SampleController is in the same package, annotating it with 'RestController' creates the bean even before the AutoConfiguration takes place. One way to stop that would be to remove the RestController annotation and configure it via the AutoConfiguration method. But then how do we programmatically register the bean as a RestController, because otherwise it just gets created as a normal object. It's mappings don't get registered

Comment: Add `@RestController` and exclude it from being component-scanned by specifying an exclude on an `@ComponentScan`. ANother option would be to add `@RequestMapping` to the class. It would be detected but it would also require `@ResponseBody` on the request handling method. However why not simply add the `@ConditionalOnProperty` to the controller instead of an auto configuration?

Comment: @M.Deinum I can't exclude it from my component-scan since I have no control over the projects that are going to import this, and I want this to be non-breaking for them. Regarding not adding ConditionalOnProperty to the Controller itself, it's because Spring doc strongly recommends against that and asks to use these annotations on AutoConfiguration classes only, hence wanted to avoid it. Your 'ResponseBody' + 'RequestMapping' on the Controller and then creating a normal 'Bean' in the config worked. Can you please add that as the answer?