# Can @ConditionalOnMissingBean be used for providing fallback bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Now I'm developing spring starter libraries, and suddenly I feel like `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` is misused in my code. Assumes that there are two auto-configuration classes.

```
@Configuration
public class ProviderAutoConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public Component component() {
        return new Component();
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(ProviderAutoConfiguration.class)
public class ConsumerAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public Component fallback() {
        return Component.NOOP;
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer consumer(Component component) {
        return new Consumer(component);
    }
}
```

The scenario is these two auto-configuration classes are in different libraries, users may only import the consumer library. So if I use `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`, the `ConsumerAutoConfiguration` will register a fallback bean to `ApplicationContext`. This behavior may cause other problems.

```
@Configuration
public class OtherProviderAutoConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public Component thirdParty() {
        return new Component();
    }
}
```

Assumes that users import another library which is developed by others. Now nobody knows the behavior of `Component` bean initialization.

```
@Configuration
public class ConsumerAutoConfiguration {

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private Component component = Component.NOOP;

    @Bean
    public Consumer consumer() {
        return new Consumer(component);
    }
}
```

So my question is should I use `@Autowired` instead of `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` in this kind of scenario? Or is there a better way than both of them?

Comment: Hi! `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` is used for conditional bean initialization, you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56903971/14394219) thread. While `@Autowired` is used for bean injection, a nice answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19419296/14394219)

Comment: @artiomi Yes I know that. My point is can I use `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` to  provide fallback bean?

Comment: @artiomi I have edited title to make question easier to understand